# VS is not using System + Unhandled exception

Tags: xamarin, app.xaml

An application I'm trying to run, throws Unhandled Exception on InitializeComponent() line in the App.xaml.cs, which says: System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000005 from typeref (expected class 'ResourceLoadingQuery' in assembly '') occurred.

At the same time I have noticed, that System (and System.IO) is not being used.

I was trying to delete bin and obj, create a new app, at the end reinstalled Visual Studio. Keeps throwing same error. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: If it is throwing on `InitializeComponent`, then check your `App.xaml` for errors. If that is not a problem, then I would highly suspect that you have a mismatch of Xamarin.Forms nuget|package versions in your different projects.